# Error blinking on iPad with createjs

Tags: ipad, createjs

I have a serious problem using CreateJS. I have an event to detect a click. It works well, except on iPad. In iPad when the event is triggered the display flashes. The example (it is all the source code):

http://intelisen.com/aulaplaneta/simple/principal.html

Any help? Thank you...